# no visible interface declares the selector 'setDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a frustrating problem. I can't wrap my head around the "delegate thing". 
My problem is that i can't set a Viewcontroller as the delegate.

```
-(IBAction)adminRegisterVC:(id)sender{
AdminSignUpViewController *adminSignUpVC = [[AdminSignUpViewController alloc] init];
[adminSignUpVC setDelegate:self]; // Gets an error message. See what error below.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:adminSignUpVC animated:YES];
}
```

it doesnt work with: `adminSignUpVC.delegate = self;` either.

error:

> No visible @interface for 'AdminSignUpViewcontroller' declares the selector 'setDelegate:'

Is there something i should add to this:

```
@interface AdminSignUpViewController : UIViewController
```

I really need some help here!

Comment: Do you have a `delegate` property in your `AdminSignUpViewController`?

Comment: What do you mean? how do i set the delegate property?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c